# Unusual signal numbers from WTERMSIG macro after waitpid()

Tags: c++, macos, signals, bsd, waitpid

I am seeing unusual signal numbers (for example 50, 80 or 117) from the following code when waiting for a child process to terminate.  I am only seeing this from one particular child process, and I have no access to the process source code and it only happens some of the time.

I want to know what these unusual values mean, given `NSIG == 32`, and where I can find some documentation in the headers or man pages?

Note that this code runs in a loop sending progressively more menacing signals until the child terminates.

```
int status, signal;

if (waitpid(m_procId, &status, WNOHANG) < 0) {
    LOGERR << "Failed to wait for process " << name() << ": " <<
        strerror(errno) << " (" << errno << ")";
    break;
} else if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    m_exitCode = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    terminated = true;
    LOGINF << "Process " << name() << " terminated with exit code " << m_exitCode;
} else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    signal = WTERMSIG(status);    // !!! signal is sometimes 50, 80 or 117 !!!
    terminated = true;
    LOGINF << "Process " << name() << " terminated by signal " << signal;
} else {
    LOGWRN << "Process " << name() << " changed state but did not terminate.  status=0x" <<
        hex << status;
}
```

This is running under OSX 10.8.4, but I have also seen it in 10.9 GM seed.

**EDIT** Modifying the code as below makes the code more robust, however sometimes the child process gets orphaned as I guess the loop doesn't do enough to kill the child process.

```
else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    signal = WTERMSIG(status);
    if (signal < NSIG) {
        terminated = true;
        LOGINF << "Process " << name() << " terminated by signal " << signal;
    } else {
        LOGWRN << "Process " << name() << " produced unusual signal " << signal
               << "; assuming it's not terminated";
    }
}
```

Note this code is part of the `Process::unload()` method of this [class](https://github.com/trojanfoe/ChessCore/blob/master/src/Process.cpp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OS X manpage for waitpid](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/waitpid.2.html), when specifing WNOHANG, you should check for a return of 0:

```
 When the WNOHANG option is specified and no processes wish to report status, wait4() returns a process
 id of 0.

 The waitpid() call is identical to wait4() with an rusage value of zero.  The older wait3() call is the
 same as wait4() with a pid value of -1.
```

The code posted does not check for this, which suggests to me that the value of `status` is likely junk (the value of the int is never initialized).  This could cause what you are seeing.

EDIT: `status` is indeed only set when `waitpid` returns > 0.

Comment: Yeah that is certainly the reason for the "funny" signal values, however can you explain why `waitpid()` would return `0` and yet the child is still alive?  I have made the changes to handle return of `0` and the children do terminate, however it takes a few loops.

Comment: I also used the `WUNTRACED` flag to `waitpid()` and it seems to have solved the issue.  I cannot award the bounty for another 4 hours, so if I forget please remind me.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped!  `waitpid` will only report status (and return >0) on a child that is stopped or has already terminated.  It sounds like your usage of `WUNTRACED`has dealt with this, though.

Comment: Yes; the child processes communicate with the main process using a text-based protocol.  I must be doing something to cause to child to stop for `SIGTTIN` et al, however it's not clear how as I don't close the pipes until after the child has terminated.  Oh well, no matter, as long as it's sorted.